# Quartz.NET trigger not firing

Tags: asp.net, automation, scheduling, quartz.net

i am using Quartz.NET in my ASP.NET web application. i put the following code in a button click handler to make sure that it executes (for testing purposes):

```
Quartz.ISchedulerFactory factory = new Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory();
Quartz.IScheduler scheduler = factory.GetScheduler();
Quartz.JobDetail job = new Quartz.JobDetail("job", null, typeof(BackupJob));
Quartz.Trigger trigger = Quartz.TriggerUtils.MakeDailyTrigger(8, 30); // i edit this each time before compilation (for testing purposes)
trigger.StartTimeUtc = Quartz.TriggerUtils.GetEvenSecondDate(DateTime.UtcNow);
trigger.Name = "trigger";
scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
scheduler.Start();
```

here's "BackupJob":

```
public class BackupJob : IJob
{
    public BackupJob()
    {
    }

    public void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
    {
        NSG.BackupJobStart();
    }
}
```

my question: why is "BackupJobStart()" not firing? i've used similar code before and it worked fine.

EDIT: @Andy White, i would have it in Application_Start in Global.asax. this doesn't work which is why i moved it to a button click handler to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 6):

Do you have the Quartz.NET logging hooked up?  I once had a problem with a job not executing (I forget why), but once I got the Quartz.NET logging going, the problem was obvious.

It's worth a try (if you're not already doing it):

- https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/quick-start.html
- http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/
- http://netcommon.sourceforge.net/documentation.html

Update: Simply add this to your program.cs to enable console logging:

```
Common.Logging.LogManager.Adapter = new Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter { Level = Common.Logging.LogLevel.Info};
```

Comment: This helped me find the issue, mine was that the class my job was executing didn't have a default (parameterless) public constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe it's a problem of time.

I've had the same problem as you, and I live in a country which time is UTC + 2. So, when I set the StartTimeUtc to the trigger, I used DateTime.Now, so the trigger didn't have to fire until two hours later, and I thought it has to be fired in the very moment my code started.

Look carefully the time of the trigger's execution and its StartTime

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was the problem MY Quartz setup didn't work. I just did something like: DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime() and it works fine.

Comment: This issue just bit me also. I had been using `.StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1))` when scheduling jobs. The really weird thing is, this used to work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is the way you're running the scheduler.  I'm not totally sure, but you may run into problems trying to run a scheduling threads in an ASP.NET application.  Putting the SchedulerFactory/Scheduler objects in a button click handler doesn't seem like it would give you the desired results.

You may need to create the scheduler at a more "global" level, so that it can run in the "background" of the application.  It might also make sense to move any scheduled work into a separate windows service, so that you don't have to maintain the scheduler in the web app.

When you had success in the past, how were you invoking the scheduler?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was an issue with IoC - there were some Interfaces that weren't implemented. I could see what was wrong with mine by adding logging:

`Common.Logging.LogManager.Adapter = new Common.Logging.Simple.ConsoleOutLoggerFactoryAdapter { Level = Common.Logging.LogLevel.Info};`

to `Program.cs` as suggested by [Andy White](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60096/andy-white)